# Django Fetch Data from multiple models connected using Foreign Keys

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, foreign-keys

I am new to Django and currently working on my first project. I have my models designed liked this:

```
    class BasketProductMapping(models.Model):
        product_reference = models.ForeignKey(Product, default=1, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        mapped_basket_name = models.CharField(max_length=5,null=False, blank=False)
        mapped_product_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, blank=False)
        def __str__(self):
            return self.mapped_basket_name

class ShelfBasketMapping(models.Model):
    mapped_basket_name_reference= models.ForeignKey(BasketProductMapping, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    mapped_name_shelf = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=False, blank=False, default='default')
    mapped_name_basket = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=False, null=False, default="default")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.mapped_name_shelf 

class KioskShelfMapping(models.Model):
    mapped_shelf_basket_name_reference = models.ForeignKey(ShelfBasketMapping, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    mapped_shelf_name = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=False, blank=False, default="default")
    mapped_kiosk_name = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=False, null=False, default="default")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.mapped_shelf_name
```

Say for my first model I have my Data like this:

```
B1 - P1
B1 - P2
B2 - P1
B3 - P1
```

and for my second models I have my data like this:

```
S1 - B1
S2 - B2
S1 - B3
```

and finally for my third model, I have my data like this:

```
K1 - S1
K2 - S2
```

Here is my serializers.py:

```
class KioskShelfMappingGetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = KioskShelfMapping
        fields = ['id', 'mapped_shelf_basket_name_reference', 'mapped_shelf_name', 'mapped_kiosk_name', 'shelf_position']
        depth = 2
```

and this is my views.py file:

```
class KioskShelfGetViewSet(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        kioskShelfMappingData = KioskShelfMapping.objects.all()
        serializer = KioskShelfMappingGetSerializer(kioskShelfMappingData, many=True)
        response = {'status':1, 'message':"Kiosk Shelf Mapping List", 'data':serializer.data}
        return JsonResponse(response, safe=False)
```

I am trying to display all the data together in a table. But the data that I am getting is in this format:

```
K1 - S1 - B1 - P1
K2 - S2 - B2 - P1
```

But I need to recieve the data in the following format:

```
K1 - S1 - B1 - P1
K1 - S1 - B1 - P2
K1 - S1 - B3 - P1
K2 - S2 - B2 - P1
```

I am unable understand why I am not getting the entire data as they are connected using Foreign Keys. Please let me know where am I going wrong. Thanks a lot for your help in advance.

Comment: You have missing links in your question you add a serializer `KioskShelfMappingGetSerializer` but never use it. You use a serializer `ShelfBasketMappingSerializer` but never show it's code... Also you appear to have duplicate data in your models. You map a basket and product by using a `CharField` being `mapped_basket_name`. Shouldn't there be a foreign key to some model `Basket`? Also you have a foreign key to `Product` yet you have a field `mapped_product_name`??

Comment: Hi Abdul. Sorry for that. I have edited my question to add the correct views.py code. I am not sure if we can have a model (BasketProductMapping)with only foreign key references only ( in this case with foreign keys to Basket and Product) and hence I have added fields along with the Foreign Key reference. I could modify it but my main issue is I am not getting the entire data as described in the question.